# Entity Framework association with Data Annotations in MVC

Tags: entity-framework, model-view-controller

I am a newbie in EF, i created a demo application in which i Assigned [StringLength] attribute to model.

```
    [Required]
    [StringLength(10)]
    public string CustomerName { get; set; }
```

This worked fine with my EF-Code First approach.

But if i am removing this attribute, then the EF is throwing exception.
I want to know the association which EF created with these attributes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> StringLength attribute can be applied to a string type property of a class. EF Code-First will set the size of a column as specified in StringLength attribute. Note that it can also be used with ASP.Net MVC as a validation attribute.

[Source](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/stringlength-dataannotations-attribute-in-code-first.aspx)

When you don't specify a length, EF Code-First will generate a `VARCHAR(MAX)`column for your `strings`. Thats the missmatch you get when you first create the column with `StringLength(10)` and remove it afterwards.